# How to enumerate downloaded files on WP7 device?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, ienumerable

Where are located downloaded documents on WP7 devices?

How can i retrieve / enumerate it?

Comment: Do you mean files downloaded into Isolated Storage?

Comment: I don't know where downloaded file are stored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `File Explorer` in the current version. When you save a document from Office, it can only be acccessed from the `Office` app. Third party apps only have access to files in their Isolated Storage or files that are exposed by [Choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).